# How to use the int[] in where IN clause in Cypher Query (using C#)

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher query

```
int[] pIds = new int[] {101, 012}; 
var query = _graphClient.Cypher.Read
            .OptionalMatch($"(p: {Labels.PERSON})")
            .Where($"p.Id IN [{pIds}]") 
            .Return<Person>(p);
```

On debugging it looks like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p: Person)
WHERE p.Id IN [System.Int32[]] 
RETURN distinct p
```

---

The values that I should pass in this where clause [101, 012], but its not. Because pIds[0] = 101, pIds[1] = 012 - and its never read in the cypher query.

Where am I going wrong and its failing to pass the values? How should I pass the int[] in the Where IN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by getting the int[] into one string seperated by ,

```
var param = string.Join(",", myIntList); 

var query = _graphClient.Cypher.Read
            .OptionalMatch($"(p: {Labels.PERSON})")
            .Where($"p.Id IN $param") 
            .Return<Person>(p)
            .WithParam("param", param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is probably to use parameters :

```
int[] pIds = new int[] {101, 012}; 
var query = _graphClient.Cypher.Read
            .OptionalMatch($"(p: {Labels.PERSON})")
            .Where($"p.Id IN $pIds") 
            .Return<Person>(p)
            .WithParam("pIds", pIds);
```

Comment: I resolved it by getting the int[] into one string seperated by ,
string.Join(",", myIntList);